# How to give different value for every dynamic list widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a custom widget looping based on item count in backend like :

```
 _showPerItem(Item items) {
List<Widget> unitItems = <Widget>[];
for (var i = 0; i < items.data.length; i++) {
  unitItems.add(
    MenuList(
      menuName: '${items.data[i].name}',
      menuDescription: '${items.data[i].description}',
      price: 'Rp. ${items.data[i].price}',
      onPressed: () {
        widget.showModal(items.data[i]);
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

then I want MenuList has integer count that can be added or remove, just like fodd ordering app. So every item has different value of item count.

I've tried using bloc, but only think single value that changed. Maybe i can use Map, but i want to hear some advice or better approach. thanks!

Comment: What is it that you actually want? It's not very clear from your question. do you want to know how to determine a unique value for your object?

Comment: @FilledStacks yes, i want to determine unique value for my widget in list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this you can use dart's hasCode property on all objects. Add a property into your model called hashCode and return the hashes of the values from there. You can use [Quiver](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver) to get the hash helper function like below.

```
int get hashCode => hash2(menuName.hashCode, price.hasCode);
```

The hashCode will then be unique. You can also add other additional values in there if you'd like and just use hash3,4,etc.

Import quiver into your model using

```
import 'package:quiver/core.dart';
```

**Update:** Based on @RandalSchwartz comment below I'd like to mention that you should use a combination of properties that are unlikely to be the same when getting a hashCode.

"*hashCode is not guaranteed to return a unique value for each object. If two objects are "equal", they must have the same hashCode, but the inverse is not true.*"

Comment: instead add hashcode to my model, how about we use shared pref ? the UI look like this pic: https://www.grab.com/th/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2017/11/grabfood-step3.png , so I want to make item count persistent in that screen when add other item

Comment: @antonovria shared preferences is for storing data to disk, not for determining the value of a unique item. That's a whole different question, if you want to persist data you can use shared prefs.

Comment: hashCode is not guaranteed to return a unique value for each object.  If two objects are "equal", they must have the same hashCode, but the inverse is not true.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz true. I should mention to use the unique values of your object to determine it's unique hashcode. Updating my answer